# Trying to pass Eval() method as an argument to a C# function that contains stored procedure components

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

Please bear with me since I'm very new to all of this. I'm trying to call a stored procedure which updates the value of a field in my db table.

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[StatusUpdate]
    @requestid VARCHAR(500)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE PeriodChangeRequest
    SET status = 'x'
    WHERE ID = @requestid
END
```

Here's my C# function that's supposed to pull in a single argument and call my stored procedure:

```
void UpdateStatus(string idString)
{
     using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection1 =  new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=xxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxxx;Integrated Security=True;Trusted_Connection=yes")) 
     using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("StatusUpdate", sqlConnection1))
     {
         cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

         cmd.Parameters.Add("@requestid", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = idString;

         cmd.Connection.Open();
     }
}
```

Function calling previous function, and passing in `Eval("ID")` as argument (is this the main problem maybe?):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateStatus(Eval("ID"));
}
```

The button with ID of `Button1` is where I'm calling the `Button1_Click()` function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../bootstrap/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="../bootstrap/vendor/jquery/jquery.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr class="table-info">
      <th scope="col">User:</th>
      <th scope="col">Rest #:</th>
      <th scope="col">Submitted on:</th>        
      <th scope="col">Goes live:</th>      
    <th scope="col">Ends:</th>
    <th scope="col">Meal Period:</th>
    <th scope="col">Permanent?:</th>
  <th scope="col"></th>
</tr>
</thead>

   <form runat="server" id="form1">
<asp:Repeater runat="server" id="Repeater1" DataSourceID="dsRequests">
   <ItemTemplate>
             <tr>
              <td><%# Eval("userName") %></td>
              <td><%# Eval("restNum") %></td>
              <td><%# Eval("dateInfo") %></td>         
              <td><%# Eval("golivedate") %></td>        
              <td><%# Eval("enddate") %></td>
              <td><%# Eval("commentText") %></td> 
              <td><%# Eval("permPeriod") %></td>
<td><button onclick="alert('<%# Eval("comment") %>')" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Comment</button> </td>

 <td>      

 <asp:Button ID="Button1"
                Text="Close"
                OnClick="Button1_Click"
                class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                runat="server" />   </td>
                 </tr></ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater> 
</form>
</table>

<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" id="dsRequests" SelectCommand="PeriodRequestGet" 
  ConnectionString="Data Source=xxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Integrated Security=True;Trusted_Connection=yes">
</asp:SqlDataSource> 

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: So what is the question? You are not calling execute method on command, did you notice that?

Comment: Do you mean     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); ? Because I just added that and still no luck.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: It looks like you form is a table and I assume ID is a column in each row of the table.  How are you getting the ID from the row of the table?  Which column of the table is the ID?

Comment: I'm trying to pass ID from my SQL table to UpdateStatus(), but the parameter is not working. I did pass a static string as a parameter to try it out and it successfully updates, but I can't do it dynamically with Eval("ID")

Comment: jdwend: ID is the second column. I am getting it via another stored procedure called PeriodRequestGet

Comment: You don't need click event handler for button. You should use `ItemCommand` event of the Repeater control. It gets executed whenever a button inside repeater is clicked. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2 and in that event you can get hold of the Repeater item and the data of the item.